# Regex for Chilean RUT/RUN with PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm having issues with the validation of the chilean RUT/RUN with a regex expression in PCRE. I have the next regular expression but sadly can't make it work:

```
\b[0-9|.]{1,10}\-[K|k|0-9]
```

I need help to see what is wrong with the code. The application I need to use only uses PCRE.

Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with the pattern? What are the pattern requirements? BTW, [check this](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2444).

Comment: [Your regex is a valid regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/1).

Comment: Yes! I checked that URL before but sadly it didn't work (it seems it's not PCRE compatible). When I tried the use the regular expression posted before, the application showed me that "the regular expression is not valid", which left me clueless.

The number has to be 8 or 9 characters long, and the last character can be a number from 0 to 9 or a K. Some examples are:

10.000.000-0
9.343.154-K
17.878.335-2

The last number is separated from the others by a hyphen.

Comment: What application did you use? It is buggy if it says your expression is invalid. And next, the expression you need must be anchored, within `^` and `$`. Well, no idea what the intial regex part should look like, but something like [`^[0-9.|]{8,10}-[Kk0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/2) *is* a valid PCRE regex.

Comment: So, have you tried this? What are sample strings you need to match?

Comment: Hello, It didn't work so I escalated a case with the developer, and he told me to use
    ([\d]{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\-[\dkK])
which worked successfully. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That means my pattern  also works, all you need is to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group. Try `^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK])$`

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK])$
```

to match and capture (that is not usually necessary, but your app requires a capturing group to extract its contents) a whole string that matches the pattern. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/3).

To match shorter strings that match this pattern inside a larger string, you may remove `^` and `$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/4)) or use `\b` word boundaries instead (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/5)).

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}` - 2 sequences of a literal `.` and 1 to 3 digits
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `[\dkK]` - a digit, `k` or `K`.
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: var str = '1.111.111-1';
var globalRegex = RegExp('\b(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK])\b/','gm');
console.log(globalRegex.test(str)); Is it right way to validate ?

Comment: @insoftservice `var globalRegex = /^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK]$/`

Comment: Thx @wiktor but issue is that i have to pass it from php to JS. So i have add single quotes.

Comment: @insoftservice Note a regex is a *text*, and how you *represent* this text in your code depends on your programming environment and this is out of current question scope (you did not specify the language tag, nor provided any code). In JS, you just use `var globalRegex = /^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK]$/` or `var globalRegex = new RegExp('^\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}-[\\dkK]$')`. In PHP, `$regex = "~^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){2}-[\dkK]$~"`.

Answer (score 1):

As they sometimes omit the dots, I used this one:

```
^(\d{1,2}(?:[\.]?\d{3}){2}-[\dkK])$
```

Details:

- ^ - start of string
- \d{1,2} - 1 or 2 digits
- (?:[.]?\d{3}){2} - 2 sequences of an optional '.' and 3 digits
- - a hyphen
- [\dkK] - a digit, k or K
- $ - end of string

1234567-k OK

12345678-k OK

1.234.567-k OK

12.345.678-k OK

known issue:
12.345678-k and 12345.678-k still OK and I do not like this :(

Comment: To avoid the inconsistency with the optional thousands dot separator: rather than allowing optional dots, you can manage different regexs (one with dots and from 7 to 8 digits, one with dots and from 4 to 6 digits, and one without dots from 1 to 8 digits): 

`^((\d{1,2}(\.\d{3}){2}|\d{1,3}\.\d{3}|\d{1,8})-[\dkK])$`

Answer (score 1):

**RUT without points:**

```
^[1-9]\d*\-(\d|k|K)$
```

Examples:

- 3403231-9 OK
- 03403231-9 WRONG
- 003403231-9 WRONG

**RUT separated with dots:**

```
^([1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2})(\.\d{3})*\-(\d|k|K)$
```

Examples:

- 3.403.231-9 OK
- 3.403.231-9 OK
- 13.571.187-K OK
- 13.571.187-k OK
- 3.4032.31-9 WRONG
- 03.403.231-9 WRONG
- 003.403.231-9 WRONG
- 013.571.187-k WRONG
- .403.231-9 WRONG
- 0.403.231-9 WRONG

**RUT separated with dots or RUT without dots:**

```
^([1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2})((\.\d{3})*|(\d{3})*)\-(\d|k|K)$
```

Examples:

- 3403231-9 OK
- 03403231-9 WRONG
- 003403231-9 WRONG
- 3.403.231-9 OK
- 3.403.231-9 OK
- 13.571.187-K OK
- 13.571.187-k OK
- 3.4032.31-9 WRONG
- 03.403.231-9 WRONG
- 003.403.231-9 WRONG
- 013.571.187-k WRONG
- .403.231-9 WRONG
- 0.403.231-9 WRONG

Note:

- The regular expressions consider the case that there must not be a zero at the beginning of the RUT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to `^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}){2}-[\dkK])$` to capture only 2 sequence of 3 digits after the first sequence of 1-3 digits.

Answer (score -1):

please consider being more specific in the REGEX build, since it matched wrong numbers, such as 17.87.335-2. Also the included one did't match formats without the dots or the hyphens.

Please consider using the following format: \b(\d{1,3}(?:(.?)\d{3}){2}(-?)[\dkK])\b

Modified prior version to try the other formats: https://regex101.com/r/2Us0j6/9